# React-Jest : axios.get.mockRejectedValue doesnt respect async-await

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using jest and enzyme for Unit Testing of a React App created using create-react-app. I have an axios call and I call other functions like `myfunction.onSuccess()` and `myfunction.onError()` from another component on success and error of the axios call respectively. I have put an assert to `expect(myfunction.onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);` This works fine for `mockResolvedValue` but not for `mockRejectedValue`. I see that async-await is not respected for `mockRejectedValue`.

I have created a sample code and used `window.alert` as the function to be called in both then and catch block to keep it simple here and expecting this function to be called once as an assert. Why is there a difference and how to tackle this?

Async.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Async extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  getAllPosts() {

    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data) {
          this.setState({ posts: response.data });
          window.alert("Data fetch Success");
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        window.alert(error.message);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.getAllPosts() }}>Fetch Posts</button>
        <ul>
          {this.state.posts.map((post) => (
            <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Async;
```

Async.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Async from './Async';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");

describe('Async Component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Async />);
  const layout = wrapper.instance();

  it('to notify success when posts', async () => {
    window.alert = jest.fn();
    const response = { data: [{ id: '1', title: 'something' }, { id: '2', title: 'something else' }] };
    axios.get.mockResolvedValue(response);
    await layout.getAllPosts();
    expect(layout.state.posts).not.toBe([])
    expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('to notify failure when error is encountered', async () => {
    window.alert = jest.fn();
    const error = { message: '500 Internal Server Error' };
    axios.get.mockRejectedValue(error);
    await layout.getAllPosts();
    expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // why doesn't this work?
  });
});
```

Comment: You can't `await layout.getAllPosts()` because that doesn't actually return the promise chain. Also you shouldn't be coupling the test to the internal component details like that; simulate a button click and wait for what's rendered to update.

Comment: okay but then how come ````await layout.getAllPosts()```` works for ````axios.get.mockResolvedValue````